# Jenkins: How to get a users LDAP groups in groovy-script

Tags: groovy, jenkins, ldap

i have setup a parametrized job for self-service deployments in Jenkins.
Users can select a version of the application and the environment to deploy to.
The available environments displayed to the user is currently just a static list of strings (choice parameter).

**Now i want to restrict deployments to some environments based on the LDAP-groups of the current user.**

The user-page in jenkins displays something like:

Jenkins Benutzer Id: maku

Groups:

```
adm_proj_a
nexus_admin
ROLE_ADM_PROJ_XY
ROLE_BH_KK
```

**How do i get these groups within a groovy-script?**

I tried to use *dynamic choice parameter (scriptler)* and get the LDAP-groups using a groovy-script but did not find my way through the Jenkins-API.

Any hints welcome

Answer (score 7, accepted):

User.getAuthorities() requires the caller to have the ADMINISTER permission. (http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/User.html#getAuthorities())

An alternative is to query the SecurityRealm directly.

```
import hudson.model.*
import jenkins.model.*

def userid = User.current().id
def auths = Jenkins.instance.securityRealm.loadUserByUsername(userid)
            .authorities.collect{a -> a.authority}
if("adm_proj_a" in auths){
...
```

Comment: Thanks Lionel! Thats of course the better solution.

Comment: I have the same problem: `Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod hudson.model.User current. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.`

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution. Just in case anybody is interested:

Within scriptler i created a script groovy-script similar to this:

```
import hudson.model.*

def allowed_environments = ["dev","test","test-integration"]  

if ("adm_proj_a" in User.current().getAuthorities() ) 
{
   allowed_environments.add("production")
}

 return allowed_environments
```

This script is used by *dynamic choice parameter (scriptler)* within my Jenkins-Job.

Now only users within the group **adm_proj_a** can see **production** as a choice.

Comment: [getAuthorities](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/User.html#getAuthorities--) requires user has Jenkins Administer privs, which stopped it being useful to limit execution based on LDAP group, as with Admin perms in jenkins they could execute everything!

Answer (score 1):

Like [ffghfgh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1053741/ffghfgh) wrote getAuthorities method requires administrator permission.Use the following:

```
def auth = hudson.model.User.current().impersonate().getAuthorities().collect {it.getAuthority()}
if ("adm_proj_a" in auth){
   // do something
}
```

Jenkins may ask admin account to approve script in "scriptApproval" section